# Codeigniter 2.1, PHP - foreach post

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have following problem:

I have input field name and input field phone and they are bound together (for example Home - 555-5555-555, Hideout - 333-333-3 ), and user can insert as many phone pairs as he wants. 
For the moment (this is old DB version which needs to be upgraded) user have one row for inserting data. 
Phone field is made in the following way;

**333-333-333,55-555-555....** and when it is needed to show phone numbers this is exploded. I would like to keep this and make phone pair in the following way **Home_55555-55,Hideout_333-33-33...**.

How can I do this and is this a good way to do this or I should do it the classical way (one row per phone pair)?

Comment: Can you show your code? It's hard to make out what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this is not the way to do it, you really want a row per phone number, furthermore, you'd want a separate field (column) for the phone type (eg. Home or Hideout). The database table should look something like this:

```
+----+----------------+--------------+
| id | phone_location | phone_number |
+----+----------------+--------------+
| 1  | Home           | 333-3333-333 |
| 2  | Hideout        | 555-5555-555 |
  ...
```

You might even want to consider a separate table for the locations (in case the 'location'-name are some sort of fixed, ie. users cannot choose the names randomly). You would create a table like this:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | phone_loaction |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | Home           |
| 2  | Hideout        |
  ...
```

And your original table would look like this:

```
| id | phone_location | phone_number |
+----+----------------+--------------+
| 1  | 1              | 333-3333-333 |
| 2  | 2              | 555-5555-555 |
  ...
```

Ofcourse this doesn't consider different users, so you would add an extra column to the phone_number table with a `user_id` column, which points to the `users` table

Comment: I see. User needs to be able to create name for his phone, so I would use first way. One more problem remains: At the moment I have just one input pair for the phone - input with name **phone_name** and input with name **phone_number**, and there is a button which adds (via JS) new pair with the same name. How should I name this new fields and later insert them (I guess it needs to go via foreach loop, but at the moment I am in the dark about this)?

Comment: you would name you fields like this: `<input type="text" name="phone_name[]" />`
That will create an array in your $_POST vars: `$_POST['phone_name'][0]` point to the first field named that way. (so the name of the fields in the html tag is exactly the same for all phone_name fields)

Comment: @giorgio: Wouldn't you do the same as well for the users? Like a phone_number id -> user id relation table?

Comment: @hakre yes you definitely need some sort of relation between phone numbers and users (if phone numbers are linked to users, and is not just a collection of phone numbers), but what kind of relation it should be depends on the use of the system. You should look into one-to-many relations (a user has multiple phone numbers) one-to-one relations (a user can only have one phone number), or maybe even many-to-many relations (a user can have many phone numbers, and users can share a phone number, eg. colleagues or family members). Google it or PM me if you have specific questions